# Client-server solution for signing and encrypting files

Tags: java, encryption, digital-signature

I'm looking for a solution to perform file encrypting and signing. This would be done on the client side, and signature check and decryption on the server side.

Some details:

- This should work for any kind of file (the signature should be "attached" to the file, not inside it like with PDFs)
- At least the server side should be Java based (the client could be a Java applet)

EDIT: The client part is really the greater issue here. While the server side can be implemented with existing libraries, the client should be an existing application (even if commercial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use PGP or something similar on the client side then. There are standards for signing and verifying signatures on messages and/or files, and there are certainly commercial and free products for this. I would recommend using PGP on the clients, and you can look up either a PGP library for Java to use on the server, or you can check out how PGP wraps up the data to emulate that (after all, signing data is a standard and well documented procedure, albeit cumbersome).

The [Bouncy Castle](http://bouncycastle.org/java.html) library for Java has some OpenPGP support, you can check it out to see how compatible it is with a PGP implementation for Windows or whatever the clients use.
Cryptix also has some OpenPGP support but that library was meant for Java 1.3 and hasn't been updated since 2005. I recommend you use BC instead.

Answer (score 2):

[The Cryptix project](http://www.cryptix.org/) is an open source java PGP library.

Comment: That project would fit the server requirements, although the client is the greater issue here.